# Заменить пробелы в строке на тире

Tags: javascript, jquery

Например, у меня есть строка `Фрукты на продажу`, и мне нужно получить строку в таком виде - `Фрукты-на-продажу`. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно обойтись и без регулярок:

```js
var str = 'Яблоки круглые и (яблоки сочные)';
console.log(str.split(' ').join('-').split('(').join('').split(')').join(''));
```

**UPD:** Можно еще добавить String новый метод `replaceAll()`:

```js
String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
};

var str = 'Яблоки круглые и (яблоки сочные)';
console.log(str.replaceAll(' ', '-').replaceAll('(', '').replaceAll(')', ''));
```

Answer (score 5):

Можно с помощью регулярного выражения и метода замены [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
var re = / /g; // Флаг g - глобальный поиск совпадений по всей строке
var str = 'Яблоки круглые и яблоки сочные';
var newstr = str.replace(re, '-');

console.log(newstr);
```

Полезная ссылка: [Регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Comment: А можете еще подсказать - какое регулярное выражение будет, в случае если строка - `Яблоки круглые и (яблоки сочные)`, будет также содержать скобки, которые нужно убрать?

Comment: @Kek либо новой регуляркой, либо в этой же: `var re = /[ |)|(]/gi;`  но если в этой же, то замена будет снова на тире. Вообще, можно почитать про регулярки тут: [Регулярные выражения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)